# Docker Error occured while trying to proxy to: localhost:5000

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

I get the following error when using a express-react app on docker.

[image]

[image]

i referred to this

[React Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/ from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:8000 (ECONNREFUSED)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50107816/react-proxy-error-could-not-proxy-request-api-from-localhost3000-to-http-l)

and the solution doesn't seem to work.

**setupProxy.js**

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy('/auth/github', { target: 'http://[::1]:5000/' }))
  app.use(proxy('/api/users/auth/github', { target: 'http://[::1]:5000/' }))
  app.use(proxy('/api/users/', { target: 'http://[::1]:5000/', "secure": false }))
  app.use(proxy('/api/posts/', { target: 'http://[::1]:5000/' }))
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:8.10.0-alpine
EXPOSE 5000
COPY . /home/app
WORKDIR /home/app
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - 5000:3000
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6.8-alpine
    expose:
      - 5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_DB: db
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "sequelize-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "client": "cd ./client && npm start ",
    "server": "nodemon app.js  --ignore client",
    "build": "echo 'hello build'",
    "start": "concurrently --kill-others   \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.6.1",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "cookie-session": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^6.2.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-flash": "0.0.2",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.4.0",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "nodemailer": "^5.1.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-github": "^1.1.0",
    "passport-github2": "^0.1.11",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "pg": "^7.8.0",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.2",
    "sequelize": "^4.42.0"
  }
}
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var userRoute = require('./routes/users');
var postRoute  = require('./routes/posts');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var models = require('./models');
var User = require('./models/user');
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser') ;
var cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
var env = dotenv.config();
var cors = require('cors');
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const passport = require('passport');
const path = require('path');


// CORS Middleware
app.use(cors());

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); 


app.use(session({
  secret : 'nodeauthsecret',
  resave: false,
 saveUninitialized: true,

}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
require('./config/passport')(passport);
require('./config/passport-github')(passport);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.user = req.user; // This is the important line
  console.log(res.locals.user);
  next();
});
// app.use(function(req, res, next) {
//   res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
//   res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
// });



app.use('/api/users', userRoute )

app.use('/api/posts',  postRoute )




app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log(`Server is running on ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Why are you publishing 5000 port and trying to connect to 3000?

Comment: because react uses port 3000, and port 5000 handles the api requests from express. This code works, if this isn't on docker.

Comment: why using port as `3000`?

Comment: sorry i updated my code its really

`1] [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/users/user from localhost:5000 to http://localhost:5000/ (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)`

Comment: could you try `http://localhost:5000/api/users/user` in your browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's make sense of this:

The API server listens for requests on default port of `5000` *in the docker container*.

The API service is composed using `docker-compose` to publish port `5000` in the node machine for target port `3000` in the container.

Then, the client server is set up to proxy API requests to port `5000` in the node machine.

Clearly, there isn't any service running on `3000` in the container.
You can correct the target port by setting it to `5000` in `docker-compose.yaml`

```
  ports:
      - 5000:5000
```

Comment: ok let me try this out, im waiting for this build to be done with.

Comment: @randal what happened?