# How to connect react js frontend with express api backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app

I am trying to create a axios post request to my express backend from my react front end

i have tried including the proxy syntax to my package json so it can interact to it and i have also tried [React Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/ from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:8000 (ECONNREFUSED)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50107816/react-proxy-error-could-not-proxy-request-api-from-localhost3000-to-http-l)

Here is my client package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },

  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
```

And here is my api request

```
axios
      .post('api/users/register', newUser)
      .then(res => console.log(res.data))
      .catch(err => this.setState({ errors: err.response.data }));
```

here is my express back end, Note i have a api folder that handles each api

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const passport = require('passport');

const users = require('./routes/api/users');
const posts = require('./routes/api/posts');
const movies = require('./routes/api/movies');

const app = express();

// Body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose
  .connect("<my mongo db>", { useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());

// Passport Config
require('./config/passport')(passport);

// Use Routes
app.use('/api/users', users);
app.use('/api/posts', posts);
app.use('/api/movies', movies);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

But my react app is running on port 3000

I expect it to output a success message in console, but here is what i got

`POST http://localhost:3000/api/users/register 404 (Not Found)  xhr.js:166`

which shows it is not communicating with my package json proxy.

Comment: what is your express configuration ?

Comment: I think your Proxy should be before the scripts object

Comment: @DimitarTsonev the express server is working fine. I already test that with both postman and insomnia

Comment: @TanveerSinghBhatia i tried it, it didn't work.

Comment: are u using `cors` in your backend?

Comment: What happens if you [configure the proxy manually](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development#configuring-the-proxy-manually)? `const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy('/api', { target: 'http://localhost:5000/' }));
};
`

Comment: @Dansiecrown please post both client and server side code somewhere on the web so that we can see it. Github repo or code sandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem might probably come from the jsx value of the form that is been submit to the express api route. Try the following solution, one of them might make it work

1. make sure the value of the component form is the same thing as the one in your express route
2. try  [configure your proxy manually](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development#configuring-the-proxy-manually) and remember to also add the proxy to your package.json.

This should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in package.json.
...
"proxy": {
    "/api": {
      "target": "https://localhost:5000",
      "secure": false
    }
  },
...