Title: Proxy Error: Could Not Proxy Request to Backend Server on Port 6000 (ECONNREFUSED)
I'm encountering a "Proxy error: Could not proxy request" when trying to access the backend route /api/v1/me from my React frontend running on localhost:3000. The error message I receive is:

Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/v1/me from localhost:3000 to
http://localhost:6000/.  ECONNREFUSED

Backend Details:

The backend is running on port 6000 and is working properly. It is
connected to the database as expected, and all routes, including
/api/v1/me, are functioning correctly when accessed directly from
Postman.

Here's the relevant part of my app.js file:
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import cors from "cors";
import { connectDatabase } from "./config/dbConnect.js";
import errorMiddleware from "./middlewares/errors.js";

const app = express();

// Load environment variables
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "PRODUCTION") {
  dotenv.config({ path: "backend/config/config.env" });
}

// Connect to the database
connectDatabase();

// Middleware for JSON and cookies
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

// Setup CORS for frontend access
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000", // Frontend URL
    credentials: true,
  })
);

// Import routes
import authRoutes from "./routes/auth.js";

// Use routes
app.use("/api/v1", authRoutes);

// Error handling middleware
app.use(errorMiddleware);

// Start the server
const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log(
    `Server started on PORT: ${process.env.PORT} in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode.`
  );
});

// Handle unhandled promise rejections
process.on("unhandledRejection", (err) => {
  console.log(`ERROR: ${err}`);
  console.log("Shutting down server due to Unhandled Promise Rejection");
  server.close(() => {
    process.exit(1);
  });
});

Route Definition:
This is the route for the /me endpoint in my backend:
router.route('/me').get(isAuthenticatedUser, getUserProfile);

And the controller method:
export const getUserProfile = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
  const user = await User.findById(req?.user?._id);
  res.status(200).json({
    user,
  });
});

Redux Action and Reducer:
I'm using Redux to manage authentication. Below is the action that calls the /api/v1/me endpoint:
export const loadUser = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: LOAD_USER_REQUEST });

    const { data } = await axios.get('/api/v1/me');

    dispatch({
      type: LOAD_USER_SUCCESS,
      payload: data.user
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: LOAD_USER_FAIL,
      payload: error.response.data.message
    });
  }
};

The authReducer handles the response:
export const authReducer = (state = { user: {} }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD_USER_REQUEST:
      return {
        loading: true,
        isAuthenticated: false,
      };

    case LOAD_USER_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        user: action.payload
      };

    case LOAD_USER_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        user: null,
        error: action.payload
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

Frontend Issue:

I'm using axios in React with Redux, and the backend is on port 6000.
I've checked that the backend is running correctly on port 6000, and
the database is connected properly.

Error:
When trying to access /api/v1/me from the React frontend on port 3000, I get the Proxy error: ECONNREFUSED. This error suggests that the request cannot be forwarded to the backend server.
I have set up a proxy in the package.json file of my React app like this:
"proxy": "http://localhost:6000"


What I have tried:

Ensured that both frontend and backend are running on their
respective ports.
Checked the backend server logs, and everything looks fine.
Made sure that CORS is configured to allow the frontend
(localhost:3000) to access the backend.
Tried restarting both the frontend and backend servers.

Can anyone suggest what could be causing this issue? Is there something wrong with the proxy configuration or how the request is being sent from the frontend?

"and everything looks fine" - how exactly? Are there no connection attempts? Check in a browser that http://localhost:6000/api/v1/me is available, it's unclear from the question if you did that. Cors is not relevant because this happens on server side where it's not applied. What is OS?

Yes i tested my api on postman and it is pretty fine working there, I am using windows OS

remove that "proxy" option and it should work fine

@ZaryabKhan It's unknown what is your react setup, please, provide it. Depending on it "proxy": "http://localhost:6000" could work, I see no explanation forECONNREFUSED . There's a related question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50107816 , check the possible workarounds, they are trial and error. As said, you may not need a proxy because you have cors configured, but it may be a useful option depending on the app

@EstusFlask I used npx create-react-app to set up my React project. The app includes a login form, and when I log in using that form, the login is successful, and the token is stored in the browser's cookies. This confirms that the backend is correctly connected to the frontend.
However, after logging in, the app redirects to another page where it makes a request to /api/v1/me. At this point, the error occurs (ECONNREFUSED).

create-react-app is not recommended and should be avoided for years. It doesn't get updates or security fixes.

@ZaryabKhan It's unclear what this means, "when I log in using that form, the login is successful", the question doesn't contain this. Is there another axios request to localhost:3000/api/ endpoint (react's port) that succeeds but then another localhost:3000/api/ request fails? Then this would mean that backend server crashes at some point. As said, there's no reasonable explanation for ECONNREFUSED here. create-react-app is obsolete but it's ok and what you try could work. Check the linked question, e.g. replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1 could possibly help.

And as said already, you don't really need a proxy here, you could make reqs to 6000 because cors is configured. Can't suggest anything else at this point
